# Mysql not exists join tables

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve this:

```
        SELECT t.trainingID,trainingEvaluation, 
    trainingAim, trainingHood, trainingExplanation, behaviorID,
        trainingTotalQuestion, 
        trainingOK, trainingCreateTime 
        FROM training t, trainingset ts, student s 
        WHERE s.studentid = ts.studentid and 
studentusername = 't' and t.trainingid = ts.trainingid
```

but if those dont exist:

```
    SELECT distinct trainingResponseScore
        FROM training t, trainingset ts, student s,trainingresponse tr
        WHERE ts.studentid = tr.studentid and studentusername = 't' 
and s.studentid = ts.studentid
     and tr.trainingid = ts.trainingid
```

i try where not exists but it gives errors.

and also this doesnot work

```
SELECT t.trainingID,trainingEvaluation, trainingAim, trainingHood, trainingExplanation, behaviorID, trainingTotalQuestion, 
trainingOK, trainingCreateTime 
FROM training t, trainingset ts, student s WHERE s.studentid = ts.studentid and studentusername = 't' and t.trainingid = ts.trainingid and t.trainingid not in (   SELECT distinct trainingResponseScore
        FROM training t, trainingset ts, student s,trainingresponse tr
        WHERE ts.studentid = tr.studentid and studentusername = 't' 
and s.studentid = ts.studentid
     and tr.trainingid = ts.trainingid)
```

Comment: *if those don't exist*  isn't very clear. I presume you mean, *if no rows match `studentusername = 't'`. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the late-20th-century way of joining tables:

```
   FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.col = table2.col
```

In MySQL it's impossible to express a `LEFT JOIN` that way, so if your join criteria fail the rows are suppressed from your result set.

Instead you should use this pattern

```
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.col = table2.col
```

For your query it might look like this:

```
SELECT t.trainingID,trainingEvaluation, 
       trainingAim, trainingHood, trainingExplanation, behaviorID,
       trainingTotalQuestion, 
       trainingOK, trainingCreateTime 
  FROM student s
  LEFT JOIN trainingset ts    ON  s.studentid = ts.studentid
  LEFT JOIN student s         ON t.trainingid = ts.trainingid
  WHERE studentusername = 't'
```

This will produce at least one result-set row for each matched row in `student`.